# How could I optimize this code (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, optimization

I'm looking to optimize the code below. It add active class on hover and remove class on hover in another element, many thanks for any suggestions.

```js
$("#1 .benefits").hover(function() {
  $('.promote-benefits #1 .benefits-text').addClass('active');
  $('.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #3 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #4 .benefits-text, .promote-benefits #5 .benefits-text ').removeClass('active');
}, function() {
  /*$('.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text').removeClass('active');           */
});
$("#2 .benefits").hover(function() {
  $('.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text').addClass('active');
  $('.promote-benefits #1 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #3 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #4 .benefits-text, .promote-benefits #5 .benefits-text ').removeClass('active');
}, function() {
  /*$('.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text').removeClass('active');           */
});
$("#3 .benefits").hover(function() {
  $('.promote-benefits #3 .benefits-text').addClass('active');
  $('.promote-benefits #1 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #4 .benefits-text, .promote-benefits #5 .benefits-text ').removeClass('active');
}, function() {
  /*$('.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text').removeClass('active');           */
});
$("#4 .benefits").hover(function() {
  $('.promote-benefits #4 .benefits-text').addClass('active');
  $('.promote-benefits #1 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #3 .benefits-text, .promote-benefits #5 .benefits-text ').removeClass('active');
}, function() {
  /*$('.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text').removeClass('active');           */
});
$("#5 .benefits").hover(function() {
  $('.promote-benefits #5 .benefits-text').addClass('active');
  $('.promote-benefits #1 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text,.promote-benefits #3 .benefits-text, .promote-benefits #4 .benefits-text ').removeClass('active');
}, function() {
  /*$('.promote-benefits #2 .benefits-text').removeClass('active');           */
});
```

Comment: This question fits better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We'd also need to see your HTML in order to help you

Comment: Look into `.not(selector)` in the jQuery documentation

Comment: Why isn't all of this just one function? There's no need to repeat ad nauseam this for each ID, just do it on the class, use $(this) to assign correct values, and remove all other .active classes before assigning. Something like `$('.benefits').hover(function() { $('.benefits-text').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active'); }`

Comment: The tricky part is the `#id`. Is this id really starts with `#1`, `#2` and so on?